# Run batch script with a server path in perl

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, cmd

I have a perl script that goes out and executes a handful of batch scripts. I am only using these batch scripts because batch can parse through a directory of 1000s of files a lot faster than perl, or at least I can't find an fast way in perl to do it. Right now the code is local, so I was using a directory path based on how I mapped my drives to start the scripts, like this:

> system("start J:/scoreboard/scripts/Actual/update_current_build.bat "."\"$rows[0][$count]\" "."\"*\" "."\"$output_file\"");

I need to make it more portable so that it can run from any machine. I tried using the server path, but when the batch script executes it says that I have an 'Invalid switch - "/".

> system("start //server/share/scoreboard/scripts/Actual/update_current_standards.bat "."\"$output_file\"");

So my ultimate question is, how do I start a batch script using the server path?

Comment: It's called a "UNC path"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Windows itself accepts `/` and `\` as a directory separator, not every program does.

```
>dir c:\
 Volume in drive C is OS
...

>dir c:/
Invalid switch - "".
```

The problem is that `/` marks the start of an option (e.g. `dir /s/b`).

You could simply use the other slash.

```
system(qq{start \\\\server\\... "$output_file"});
```

---

For many of these programs, quotes disambiguate.

```
>dir "c:/"
 Volume in drive C is OS
...
```

So we just the need to execute `start "//..."`? No. `start` has a *weird* syntax. If the first argument is quoted, it's treated as the title to use for the console.

```
start cmd        # Ok
start "cmd"      # XXX
start "" "cmd"   # Ok
```

So you will need something like the following:

```
system(qq{start "" "//..." "$output_file"});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. This isn't a case where quotes help. It really does want `\`.

Comment: Ok your explanation and everything makes sense, but is saying that "The sytem cannot find the path specified" and that it "Cannot find the file \\..\..\update_current_standards.bat"

Comment: I got rid of the "Cannot find file" error because I had the path wrong, but I am still getting "The system cannot find the path specified" error. The path now looks like: `system(qq{"start \\\\server\\share\\scoreboard\\scripts\\Actual\\update_current_build.bat "."\"$rows[0][$count]\" "."\"*\" "."\"$output_file\""}); `

Comment: Alright NOW it is working. I didn't realize that you didn't have the quotes before start and around the path. Thanks!!!

Comment: I used `qq{..."...}` instead of `"...\"..."`. They mean the same thing, but the former is just a tad cleaner.